# Are there more ways to define a tuple with only one item?

Tags: python, singleton, tuples

I know this is one way, by placing a comma:

```
>>> empty = ()
>>> singleton = 'hello',    # <-- note trailing comma
>>> len(empty)
0
>>> len(singleton)
1
>>> singleton
('hello',)
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Are there more ways to define a tuple with only 1 item?

Comment: *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*

Comment: @BenJames ...but surely _"Readability counts"_ :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> tuple(['hello'])
('hello',)
```

But the built-in syntax is there for a reason.

Comment: @Edan: Less code using the built-in, but the trailing comma doesn't really jump out an say "TUPLE!"... my eyes might miss it.

Comment: Singleton tuples are something of a curiosity, to be sure. Here's GVR's justification for their existence: http://www.python.org/search/hypermail/python-1992/0292.html

Comment: [Here is a mirror](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/python/search/hypermail/python-1992/0292.html) for the broken link in above comment by @JoshLee

Answer (score 5):

Even though you can define a tuple as `'hello',` I think it would be easy for someone to possibly miss the trailing comma if they were reading your code.  I definitely prefer 
`('hello',)` from a readability stand-point.

Answer (score 2):

`singleton = ('hello',)`

This is more clear I guess, and @jleedev even more clear. But I like the method you used the best:

`singleton = 'hello',`

Answer (score 2):

Another one is

```
>>> (1, 2)[0:1]
(1,)
```

A very obfuscated way, but it *is* an alternative...